# Binary tree algorithms

Tags: java, binary-tree

I have come across the following algorithm that inserts five nodes into a binary tree and then traverses the tree.

What kind of tree structure is being created? Is it balanced or unbalanced? How can you tell? Would that affect the type of traversal the algorithm is conducting?

```
import Prog1Tools.IOTools;

class Node {
    Node left;
    Node right;
    int value;

    public Node(int value) {
        this.value = value;
    }
}

public class GeneralTreeTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        // build a simple tree add 5 nodes to the tree
        Node root = new Node(5);
        System.out.println("Tree Example");
        System.out.println("Building tree with root value " + root.value);
        insert(root, 1);
        insert(root, 8);
        insert(root, 6);
        insert(root, 3);
        insert(root, 9);
        System.out.println("Traversing tree ");
        printOrder(root);

    }

    public static void insert(Node node, int value) {
        if (value < node.value) {
            if (node.left != null) {
                insert(node.left, value);
            } else {
                System.out.println(" Inserted " + value + " to left of "
                    + node.value);
                node.left = new Node(value);
            }
        } else if (value > node.value) {
            if (node.right != null) {
                insert(node.right, value);
            } else {
                System.out.println(" Inserted " + value + " to right of "
                    + node.value);
                node.right = new Node(value);
            }
        }
    }

    public static void printOrder(Node node) {
        if (node != null) {
            printOrder(node.left);
            System.out.println(" Traversed " + node.value);
            printOrder(node.right);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Appears to be unbalanced. Should be easy to lookup the definition of a balanced binary tree an draw the one you created

Answer (score 0):

> Is it a balanced one or and unbalanced one?

You don't have any balancing logic. For example, you insert 1,2, 3, then all nodes would be continue to the right. In an AVL balanced tree, for example, the 1 would "rotate left", and 2 would become the root, therefore balancing the tree.

> how can you tell whether it is one or the other

You could draw out the pointers of the Node data structures in your tree.

> would that affect the type of traversal the algorithm is conducting.

Shouldn't. You are currently printing left, the root then right. Same order would apply to any type of binary tree